# How to increase the UI font size in SQL Developer Data Modeler 18.2?

Tags: oracle-sql-data-modeler

I am using Data Modeler 18.2 and I want to increase the font size of the Interface, but I cannot find a way to do it. I managed to do in the main sqldeveloper, but even though I've searched through many folders and config files, in data modeler I cannot find a way. I'd appreciate it if someone knows the trick!